# Summarize and Transpose rows to columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, transpose, summary

This is my input data:

```
Program = c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
Age = c(10,30,30,12,32,53)
Gender = c("F","F","M","M","M","F")
Language = c("Eng","Eng","Kor","Kor","Other","Other")
df = data.frame(Program,Age,Gender,Language)
```

I would like to output a table like this:

| Program | MEAN AGE | ENG | KOR | FEMALE | MALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |  |  |
| B |  |  |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |  |  |

Where MEAN AGE is the average age, ENG,KOR,FEMALE,MALE are counts.

I have tried using dplyr and t() but in this case I feel like I'm completely lost as to what are the steps (my first post, new to this). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the following approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Program) %>%
  summarise(
    `Mean Age` = mean(Age),
    ENG = sum(Language=="Eng"),
    KOR = sum(Language=="Kor"),
    Female = sum(Gender=="F"),
    Male = sum(Gender=="M"),
    .groups="drop"
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Program `Mean Age`   ENG   KOR Female  Male
  <chr>        <dbl> <int> <int>  <int> <int>
1 A             23.3     2     1      2     1
2 B             22       0     1      0     2
3 C             53       0     0      1     0
```

---

**Note:** `.groups` is a special variable for `dplyr` functions. The way it's used here is equivalent to using `%>% ungroup()` after the calculation. If you type any other name in the `summarise` function, it will assume it's a column name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however when i tried this I get just one row of data with a column named .group

Comment: Have you copied the exact code chunk in here? It worked normally for me. Which version of `dplyr` are you using? I'm using the version 1.0.2.

Comment: If you got a column named `.group` you didn't copy the exact code I provide. I guess you've typed `.group="drop"` (it should include "s"). Please copy and paste to see if it work.

Comment: Yes I copied the exact chunk. it seems its not reading the group_by function correctly as there are no program column. im using 0.8.5

Comment: i copied exact chunk, i noticed the group_by function for my dplyr doenst get read in alot of the dplyr code I've written! how can i upgrade the package? i tried installing it again but the package version still says 0.8.5. thanks

Comment: Try this: `install.packages("dplyr", version='1.0.2')`.

Comment: I restarted R and somehow it worked! Now I see the correct number of rows. I still get one extra column named ".groups" with "drop" as the populated cells. I will just remove that column, not sure why but perhaps because it's not allowing me to upgrade the dplyr package version even though I tried your suggestion. Thank you so much, appreciate your help :)

Comment: This is the warning I see after running the code:
Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?

Comment: I've just updated the answer to use a different `ungroup` approach. If you want to convert it back to data.frame, just use `%>% as.data.frame` then you don't need ungroupping at all. I just used it because it's a best practice as it avoid doing further unexpected calculation in the dataframe.

Comment: I didn't get any warnings... I recommend to update the package, as it has gained [a lot of functionalities](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html) since version 0.8.5. For example, `.groups` emerged in version 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```
df1 <- cbind(df[1:2], stack(df[3:4])[-2])
cbind(aggregate(Age~Program, df, mean),as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1[-2])))
  Program      Age Eng F Kor M Other
A       A 23.33333   2 2   1 1     0
B       B 22.00000   0 0   1 2     1
C       C 53.00000   0 1   0 0     1
```